# jQuery validate textarea:filled

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

i have the following form fields...

```
<textarea name="anchors[]" id="anchors1" cols="45" rows="5" class="linkbox"></textarea>
<textarea name="anchors[]" id="anchors2" cols="45" rows="5" class="linkbox"></textarea>
<textarea name="urls[]" id="urls1" cols="45" rows="5" class="linkbox"></textarea>
<textarea name="urls[]" id="urls2" cols="45" rows="5" class="linkbox"></textarea>
```

which i'm trying to validate so that if say anchors2 is filled in, then urls2 must also be filled in, however i can't for the life of me get the following to work!...

```
var validator = $("#projectform").validate({
    rules: {
        project_label: "required",
        keywords: "required",
        urls2: { required: "#anchors2:filled" }
    },
    messages: {
        project_label: "Enter a project label",
    }
    ,errorElement: "div" 
    ,submitHandler: function(form) { 
        $('input[type=submit]').attr('value', 'Please wait');
        $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        this.form.onsubmit(); return false; 
    }   

});
```

When i click submit the project_label and keywords fields validate(or not) as would be expected, however i see nothing with regards to the anchors[] and urls[] fields. I have css set on the textarea.error to give a visual indiciation too but i don't see that either when attempting to validate.

It should be noted that the following doesn't work either, which may shed some light?

```
urls1: "required",
```

Comment: What does your whole .validate() code look like? What is the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: Updated with full validate() and behaviour :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validation plugin requires that you use the element *name*, not the *id*. In order to do this, I had to change the name to remove the []. So rename your textarea, and try again - like so:

HTML:

```
<textarea name="url2newname" id="urls2" cols="45" rows="5" class="linkbox"></textarea>
```

Javascript Snippet:

```
rules: {
        project_label: "required",
        keywords: "required",
        urls2newname: { required: "#anchors2:filled" }
    }
```

Comment: Ideally i would like it to work in reverse too, however the bigger problem is that i cannot get it to work with just that single rule either.

Comment: Please post your entire validate() call, and describe the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: That works, thanks! I presume this means we can't sent a multidimensional array to php then like this, not a huge problem though, i can redo the server side scripting :)

Comment: Yeah I wouldn't overload the name attribute by trying to store the name and an array. Store the array in a hidden variable or in the value attribute.